# new Activity instance gets created after redirect from other application or browser

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I am having a problem with activity instance getting created when it gets a re direct from browser .
The problem is :-
Activity A invokes browser to do some stuff with flag -  `FLAG_ACITIVTY_NEW_TASK` .
Browser redirects back to Activity A with the specified URL scheme of the Activity A.
After redirect Activity A checks for  the tokens and other params from the intent.
Activity A resets its intent back to default by `setIntent()`.

Issue:-

After setting intent , on Same activity if I call `getIntent()`, it gives the intent by which browser invokes Activity A.
And after pressing back i again see the Activity A instance with the intent I set previously.
i.e 
stack looks like 
A-Browser Activity -A'

I think A is the new instance of Activity A getting created but actual changes get reflected in activity A.
same issue arises when i display an alert dialogue.
when clear A' from the back stack i see the alert dialogue in activity A which i display after getting redirect from browser.

At first place I don't expect a new instance getting created(A').

I checked the scenario with setting launchMode of Activity A to signleTop but same behavior.

I appreciate your inputs .

Comment: Did you launch your app from an IDE (Eclipse, IntelliJ), or after installing it with the intaller directly via the "OPEN" button? Or did you launch it by selecting it from the list of installed applications on the home screen?

Comment: i installed the app from the eclipse directly which internally invokes the browser to do some stuff

Comment: Try launching the app, not from Eclipse, but by starting it yourself from the HOME screen. See if that makes a difference.

Comment: i tried but same issue .

Comment: OK. If your app launches the browser in another task and then the browser launches your app and you want it to return to the same instance of the activity, then you must declare the activity as `launchMode="singleTop"`. You say you tried that and it didn't work. Please post the code you use to launch the browser and the URL specification that the browser uses to return to your app, and the relevenat parts of your app's manifest.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for posting this late , 
Here is the solution for this :

Have you activity's launch mode as : singleTask 
By this the framework will avoid recreating a new instance for the same activity if already alive, doing this you activity instance will be brought up and  will receive onNewIntent() 
callback instead of onResume() . Have your logic in onNewIntent()

Hope this helps ! 
Thanks .